# Is there a better way to convert a dict to [k1,v1,k2,va]?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Right now I was using the following but i feel there is a better way:

```
data = { "foo": 5, "bar": 10}
l = []
for k in data:
  l.append(k)
  l.append(data[k])

print(l)
```

I was leveraging Parameterized Queries for Postgres.  So i was trying to build the array from a dict of data.

While this *does* give me an answer, bu i was thinking that these 4 lines could be condensed a bit

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, chain the items.

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> data = {"foo": 5, "bar": 10}
>>> list(chain.from_iterable(data.items()))
['foo', 5, 'bar', 10]
```

Comment: Depending on your tastes for syntax, `list(chain(*d.items()))` will work as well. (I like `from_iterable`, though, which you can tell if you can see my deleted answer :)

Comment: `chain.from_iterable` should be more efficient since `*d.items()` will construct a tuple of all of the items to be passed to the vargs parameter, whereas `from_iterable` will just iterate over the items.

Answer (score 2):

with reduce

```
from functools import reduce

data = { "foo": 5, "bar": 10}
>>> list(reduce(lambda k,v: k+v,data.items()))
['foo', 5, 'bar', 10]
```

Comment: Also a good solution, though reduce doesnt exist in itertools, but instead in functools. im curious if this is better than chain.from_iterables or if it is comparable.

Comment: thanks for notice. I was doing it from head and I confused libraries

Comment: @Fallenreaper to be honest, I thing best solution is the one in your question. Its clear so you doesnt waste time understanding what is going on, minimal overhead, no extra lib. Only downside is that it doesnt look that good

Answer (score 1):

Another one-line way:

```
sum([[k,v] for k, v in data.items()], [])
```

Comment: The thing i can see from this is that it would have to construct a list of subarrays before concatinating them all together.  It would in my mind, run through and process the array twice.